# How to balance the Elastic search nodes using TransportClient java code

Tags: elasticsearch

looking for expert's help(i am newbie on elastic search)... have multiple nodes of elastic search.

i am using ElasticSearch java lib for indexing the json docs. would like to know how to handle the node balancing,is it possible to handle that from client side?

---elasticSearch transport client code------

```
public static Client getTransportClient(String host, int port) {
     Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                                              .put("cluster.name", "ccw_cat_es")
                                              .put("node.name", "catsrch-pdv1-01")
                                              .build();
      return new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(host, port));
   }
   public static IndexResponse doIndex(Client client, String index, String type, String id, Map<String, Object> data) {
       return client
                    .prepareIndex(index, type, id)
                    .setSource(data)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = getTransportClient("catsrch-pdv1-01", 9200);
        String index  = "orderstatussearch";
        String type   = "osapi";
        String id     = null;       
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("OrderNumber", "444");
        data.put("PO", "123");
        data.put("WID", "ab234");

        id= "444";
        IndexResponse result = doIndex(client, index, type, id, data);
    }
```

Comment: The `TransportClient` will automatically use a round robin strategy to load balance against nodes that it is connected too (by sniffing, you can connect to all data nodes automatically). The `NodeClient` will appropriately route and round robin across the cluster.

Comment: thx for ans.. why down voted??i did some research and didnt find any concrete ans as you provided.

Comment: Your question is too broad and node balancing does not fall within SO's umbrella; it's more of a server exchange issue.

Comment: Can you tell me how and where I should ask these elastic search problem...I taged it in elastic search only...more over I am looking for some code snippet for same...if you can't vote.. that's fine but don't down vote

Comment: If it's a coding question, then please rephrase your request with pseudo code.

Comment: Downvotes aren't a problem, seriously (and you cannot change a vote until the post is modified). They're just a way to push for a clearer question. If you add pseudocode that clarifies the question in a good way to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TransportClient` will automatically use a round robin strategy to load balance against nodes that it is connected too. In your case, you are only connecting to one node, so there is nothing to balance. You *can* add other nodes to the list and it will balance them appropriately.

Alternatively, you can "sniff" out the data nodes automatically by just connecting to one of them with an extra setting applied:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    // ...
    .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
    // ...
    .build()
```

This will then round robin against all data nodes that it finds in the cluster state.

This probably leads to the question: why isn't this the default? The reason is that, if you have standalone client nodes, then they are better proxies to the cluster rather than directly communicating with data nodes. For smaller clusters, this is a perfectly acceptable strategy though.